# regex for string with backslash for escape

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with a pattern for finding every text that is between double or single quotation marks in java source code. This is what I have:

```
"(.*?)"|’(.*?)’
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LJIxkfPASEJkvLdi)

This works for almost every case I guess except one:

```
"text\"moretext\"evenmore"
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Zgl_O8617F6mP_k5)

This could be used as a valid String definition, because the quotes are escaped. The pattern does not recognize the inner part more text.

Any ideas for a pattern that accounts for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex to match single or double quotes string ignoring all escaped quotes:

```
(["'])([^\\]*?(?:\\.[^\\]*?)*)\1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nk1vcl/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(["'])`: Match single or double quote and capture it in group #1
- `(`: Start Capturing group #2

  - `[^\\]*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters that is not a `\`
  - (?:`: Start non-capturing group

    - `\\`: Match a `\`
    - `.`: Followed by any character that is escaped
    - `[^\\]*?`: Followed by 0 or more of any non-`\` characters
  - `)*`: End non-capturing group. Match 0 or more of this non-capturing group
- `)`: End capturing group #2
- `\1`: Match closing single or double quote matches in group #1

Comment: That is not simpler since it doesn't match single quoted strings.

Comment: `"text\"moretext\"ev'en'more"` is a valid Java string but that is not matched by your regex.

Comment: I really like that you actually explained your answer, not just posting some regex. That greatly helps everyone visiting this question.

Comment: @cyden your regex prevent ``\`` to be last character in string, but that means it prevents strings like `"path\\to\\some\\location\\"`.

Answer (score 3):

That should work: `"([^"\\]|\\.)*"|'([^'\\]|\\.)*'` [Regexr test](http://regexr.com/3ggfc).

Explanation:

1. `"` matches **"**.
2. `[^"\\]|\\.` negates match of \ & "(i.e. makes it to consume \") or continues match of \ and any character.
3. `*` continue match.
4. `"` matches **"**

Same for `'`.

Comment: It may also match `"abc'` and won't match this correctly: `'textmo"re"textevenmore'`

Comment: @anubhava Edited.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Updated.